# how to post raw data from angular 7 to asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular7

how to post string from angular 7 to asp.net web API core 2.1

from angular i am trying below code

```
getDecTokenDetails(token: string): Observable<string> 
{
    //return this.http.get<String>("/api/MicroApp/manju");
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    debugger;
    return this.http.post<string>("/api/MicroApp", token, { headers: headers 
    });
  }
```

**IN webapi controller below code i am using**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            return Ok("toekn received " + value);

        }
```

below error i am getting

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3974/api/MicroApp", ok: false, …}

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For `bad request`, it is caused that you did you set `Content-Type` header correctly. For `let headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');`, `headers` is immutable object. Invoking class methods will return a new instance as result.

And for passing string, you need to use `""` like

```
getDecTokenDetails(token: string): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<string>("/api/SampleData/TT", `"${token}"`, {
    headers: headers
    });
}
```

Comment: @ManjunathaT Check the network tab in web browser and share us the request

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this to see if it work

```
return this.http.post<string>("/api/MicroApp", { value: token }, { headers: headers });
```